# What does this regex `str.gsub(/\#{(.*?)}/)` do?

Tags: ruby, regex

`.*` means any character, so why is the `.*?` needed in the following?

```
str.gsub(/\#{(.*?)}/) {eval($1)}
```

Comment: the ? means: make the quantifier lazy. take a look at this site:www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: This regex will do something, which you should only do with `$SAFE >= 1` on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.*` is a greedy match, whereas `.*?` is a non-greedy match. See [this link](http://www.itworld.com/nl/perl/01112001) for a quick tutorial on them. Greedy matches will match as much as they can, while non-greedy matches will match as little as they can.

In this example, the greedy variant grabs everything between the first `{` and the last `}` (the last closing brace):

```
'start #{this is a match}{and so is this} end'.match(/\#{(.*)}/)[1]
# => "this is a match}{and so is this"
```

while the non-greedy variant reads as little as it needs to make the match, so it only reads between the first `{` and the first successive `}`.

```
'start #{this is a match}{and so is this} end'.match(/\#{(.*?)}/)[1]
# => "this is a match"
```